# How to fix a RedirectResponse RouteNotFoundException in Symfony4

Tags: symfony4

I am working through [How to Build a Login Form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) in Symfony 4.1 documentation. In the 'Finishing the Login Form' section, I added the line:

```
return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('Welcome'));
```

in the onAuthenticationSuccess function. Instead of the expected Welcome page, I get a Symfony exception with the following error:

```
RouteNotFound Exception
Unable to generate a URL for the named route "Welcome" as such route does not exist.
```

I have entered the route in my routes.yaml file as:

```
# welcome page
app_welcome:
    path: /Welcome
    controller: App\Controller\Welcome::emptyPage
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging around a bit, I checked to see if my routes were correct with:

```
php bin/console debug:router
```

and realized that I was using the route **path** instead of the route **name**. Hope this saves someone else some time.

Before you can use the annotations in Symfony 4, make sure you have run:

```
composer require annotations
```

as discussed in the Symfony Docs [Routing](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html) section.